# Word for: feeling of relief in realizing you don't have a responsibility you thought you had

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, language-formation

For example, waking up from a dream where you had an assignment due you didn't do but in waking you realize it was only a dream and you didn't actually have an assignment due, and feeling relief.

Looking for a word with this meaning to **replace** a word in a language other than English...

Edited

Comment: But we don't provide words in languages other than English.

Comment: *Relieved* is really a good word. In some contexts it means no longer anxious, but in the expression *relieved of duty*, it also means no longer responsible.

Comment: Are you looking for a single word or a phrase? You may want to add a tag to your question.

Comment: It's called the relief you feel from waking up from a bad dream. Apparently you have a word for that in the other language you have in mind. Dunno of an English word for it. Try translating your word... And see http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info.

Comment: The fear/anxiety *evaporates*. For example, *As the dream faded, his anxiety evaporated*.

Answer (score 3):

If it were a real obligation (or risk) that was avoided, rather than an imaginary one, you could say *[dodge a bullet](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dodge_a_bullet)*

> To have a narrow escape; to avoid injury, disaster, or some other undesirable situation.

*Wiktionary.com*

Answer (score 3):

I would use the word you suggested in the title:

[*Relieved*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/relieved?searchDictCode=all)

> ADJECTIVE
>
> No longer feeling distressed or anxious; reassured:

The predominant meaning is closely connected to a special use:

*[Relieved of duty](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/relieve+one+of+duties)*

> *relieve one of duties*
>
> Euph. to fire someone; to dismiss someone from employment
>
> *After the scandal, she was relieved of her duties at the embassy.*

So the word addresses the inner feeling as well as the external reality: you are no longer responsible for the imaginary duties of your dream.

Answer (score 2):

You'd be feeling **spared**.

> To save from strain, discomfort, embarrassment, or the like, or from a particular cause of it.

Comment: "Unburdened" is a single word that connotes being relieved or excused from a duty, particulary an unpleasant one, which is seen as "onerous" (from Latin "onus" )